# Github Desktop: "Update from <branch>" button

Tags: git, github-for-windows

In this picture below from the Github(c) Desktop App there ist this button "Update from master" (in this case). I was wondering if anyone had the insight what exact **git** function it triggers. Primarily I'm interested if *merge* or *rebase* is used. (I could not find any sort of log console).

[image]

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The git commands underlying the buttons in GitHub Desktop are not well-documented, so I investigated a while back. I concluded that the "Update from..." button dispatched

```
git merge --no-ff -m "Merge <auto_text> <branch_name>" <branch_name>
```

or something nearly identical with the "Compare" branch set to `<branch_name>` in the GitHub Desktop GUI.

I reached the conclusion in the following way:

First, I forked a repository that I control to my GitHub account. Then, I cloned the repository from my GitHub account to my local machine. Next, I committed a small change to the (original) main remote repository. Finally, I used `git fetch <remote_name_assigned_to_main_repo>` (`<remote_name>`, hereafter) to bring the single commit to my local machine. After this `fetch`, the "Update from..." button lit up.

This set up a scenario in which the branch checked out, `master` in my local repository, was one commit behind `master` in the main remote repository. By default, `git merge <remote_name>` would have produced a fast-forward merge (without a merge commit).

Using the "Update from..." button, however, resulted in the following `reflog` entry:

```
HEAD@{0}: merge <remote_name>/master: Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
```

And a merge commit in the `log`:

```
Merge remote-tracking branch '<remote_name>/master'
```

(The 'recursive' strategy "...is the default merge strategy when pulling or merging one branch." per the manual.)

I also set up a scenario in which `git rebase` might have been an option, but saw the same merge behavior.

Comment: GitHub likely chose this design, requiring a merge commit even where a fast-forward merge or a rebase might be preferred, out of conservatism. GitHub Desktop users are likely new to Git and a merge commit can be undone with `git revert` whereas a fast-forward merge or rebase cannot.

Answer (score 4):

When I hover over the button, it explicitly says "Merge XX commits from "

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Just go into "Branch" menu, then "Merge into current branch..." and choose the branch you want to get your "update" from.

Comment: Not an answer to this question.

Comment: this is what I was looking for though!

Comment: When it says "Merge master into dev" it means that all stuff from master will be sent to dev? Keeping both in sync?

Comment: and I was searching for the answer to question "What this command does if my branch is based not on master, but on another branch?" and finally ended up using the above suggestion instead of the "Update from master" option.

Answer (score 2):

GitHub themselves say it's just `git merge <defaultBranch>`.

To quote the official comments on the [issue](https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/4717) in the GitHub Desktop repo:

> This menu item emits the `update-branch` message to the main window (what we call the renderer in Electron terminology). The `updateBranch` method then looks for your default branch (typically `master`). Git operations in the app use the Git command line, so what we're doing in the app is just a `git merge master` into your current branch.)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30930215)

Comment: @SimasJoneliunas noted, my answer has been updated